How to display a success or failure message after an AJAX call in an ASP.NET webforms app
I am working on an ASP.NET webforms project written in VB.Net. I want to call a web method in the code behind using Ajax. The button click event correctly calls the code behind method. However after completion, neither the OnSucceeded nor the OnFailed methods are called.
When I used Chrome tools to debug, and hover over the PageMethods.DisableUserStatus()("", OnSucceeded, OnFailed); line,  I see this error:

Uncaught TypeError:  PageMethods.DisableUserStatus() is not a function

This is my code:
<WebMethod()>
 Public Shared Function DisableUserStatus() As JavaScriptSerializer
     Users.UpdateUserStatus("EXTERNALUSER", False)
     Dim stats As JavaScriptSerializer = New JavaScriptSerializer()

     stats.Serialize("Success")
 End Function

ASPX page markup:
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnDisableUserStatus').click(function () {
            let result = confirm('Are you sure you want to disable users?');                
            if (result == true) {
                DisableUserStatus();
            }                
        });
    });
    
    function DisableUserStatus() {
        PageMethods.DisableUserStatus()("", OnSucceeded, OnFailed); 
    }
    function OnSucceeded(result) { alert(result) }
    function OnFailed(error) { alert(error.get_message()) }
</script>


Ok, first of all, you don't need nor want to "serialize" the return value, as that part is automatic and built in for you.
So, say this markup:
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"
        EnablePageMethods="true">
    </asp:ScriptManager>

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="test web method"
        OnClientClick="mytest();return false" />
    <input id="Button2" type="button" value="button 2"
        onclick="mytest()" />

    <script>

        function mytest() {

            PageMethods.DisableUserStatus(MyGoodResult, MyBadResult)

        }

        function MyGoodResult(Result) {

            alert(Result)
        }

        function MyBadResult(MyError) {
            alert(MyError)
        }

    </script>

</form>

Note closely how we MUST drop in a ScriptManager, and we must set EnablePageMethods="true".
As noted, simply define the WebMethod as any type you want, and thus in this example, type string will suffice.
Hence, code behind is this:
<WebMethod()>
Public Shared Function DisableUserStatus() As String

    'Users.UpdateUserStatus("EXTERNALUSER", False)

    Return "Success from Server"

End Function

And the result is now this:

And here is an example showing how the return value is automatic serialized for you. Let's return a HotelName, and FirstName, and LastName.
Say this code behind:
Structure MyHotel
    Dim HotelName As String
    Dim FirstName As String
    Dim LastName As String
End Structure


<WebMethod()>
Public Shared Function GetHotel(HotelID As Integer) As MyHotel

    Dim strSQL As String =
        "SELECT HotelName, FirstName, LastName FROM tblHotelsA
        WHERE ID = @ID"

    Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL)
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = HotelID

    Dim rstData As DataTable = MyRstP(cmdSQL)

    Dim OneHotel As new MyHotel

    If rstData.Rows.Count > 0 Then            
        OneHotel.HotelName = rstData.Rows(0)("HotelName")
        OneHotel.FirstName = rstData.Rows(0)("FirstName")
        OneHotel.LastName = rstData.Rows(0)("LastName")
    End If

    Return OneHotel

End Function

Note close, we are returning a type of MyHotel, and thus serializing is automatic, and in fact it is a JSON object client side.
Client-side code can thus be:
    <asp:Button ID="cmdGetHotel" runat="server" Text="Get Hotel information"
        OnClientClick="gethotel();return false" />

    <script>

        function mytest() {

            PageMethods.DisableUserStatus(MyGoodResult, MyBadResult)

        }

        function MyGoodResult(Result) {

            alert(Result)
        }

        function MyBadResult(MyError) {
            alert(MyError)
        }


        function gethotel() {
            var testid = 20203  // an existing ID in database for testing

            PageMethods.GetHotel(testid,MyHotelResult, MyError)

        }

        function MyHotelResult(MyOneHotel) {

            var mystring = "Hotel name = " + MyOneHotel.HotelName + "\n" +
                "User name = " + MyOneHotel.FirstName + " " + MyOneHotel.LastName

            alert(mystring)

        }

        function MyError(errInfo) {
            alert(errInfo)

        }

    </script>

Note that we can thus return many values, since it is a MyHotel object as a client-side object (as JSON).
The result is thus this:


Hi Albert, thank you so much for your elaborate answer. I followed your suggestions exactly. Now the Javascript error message on the PageMethod is gone. Still, once completed successfully, it doesn't display the success alert message.

Edit your post, and post the exact code you are using. After all, the posted examples I show do work just fine, and without a reproducible example of code, then it becomes difficult to suggest what the issue is you are having. I would consider building a test page, and see if that works.

Also, are you using Friendly URL's? (this matters). and also, I suggest you clear your browser cache (even a ctrl-F5 to refresh - that will re-load browser JavaScript).
